# Part of custom loss function not differentiable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

For my problem, I want to predict customer review scores ranging from 1 to 5. I thought it would be good to implement this as a regression problem because a predicted 1 from the model while 5 being the true value should be a "worse" prediction than 4. It is also wished, that the model performs somehow **equally good for all review score classes**. Because my dataset is highly unbalanced I want to create a own loss function. With a normal MSE implemenation the model will only be good at predicting the majority class. Therefore I want to estimate the MSE for every review class (1,2,3,4 and 5 star reviews) and then take the mean of these five MSE scores. That's how the model should be incentivized to also perform good at predicting the smaller classes.

The following code shows my tensorflow loss function:

```
def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_t = tf.cast(tf.Variable(y_true, validate_shape=False),dtype="float16")
    y_pred_t = tf.cast(tf.Variable(y_pred, validate_shape=False),dtype="float16")

    one = tf.cast(tf.Variable([1]),dtype="float16")
    two = tf.cast(tf.Variable([2]),dtype="float16")
    three = tf.cast(tf.Variable([3]),dtype="float16")
    four = tf.cast(tf.Variable([4]),dtype="float16")
    five = tf.cast(tf.Variable([5]),dtype="float16")

    # index for a given review class
    i_one = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true_t, one))
    i_two = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true_t, two))
    i_three = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true_t, three))
    i_four = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true_t, four))
    i_five = tf.where(tf.equal(y_true_t, five))

    # predictions for the found indicies for a review class
    y_pred_one=tf.gather(y_pred_t,i_one)
    y_pred_two=tf.gather(y_pred_t,i_two)
    y_pred_three=tf.gather(y_pred_t,i_three)
    y_pred_four=tf.gather(y_pred_t,i_four)
    y_pred_five=tf.gather(y_pred_t,i_five)

    y_true_one=tf.gather(y_true_t,i_one)
    y_true_two=tf.gather(y_true_t,i_two)
    y_true_three=tf.gather(y_true_t,i_three)
    y_true_four=tf.gather(y_true_t,i_four)
    y_true_five=tf.gather(y_true_t,i_five)

    mse1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.square(y_true_one-y_pred_one),dtype="float"))
    mse2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.square(y_true_two-y_pred_two),dtype="float"))
    mse3 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.square(y_true_three-y_pred_three),dtype="float"))
    mse4 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.square(y_true_four-y_pred_four),dtype="float"))
    mse5 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.square(y_true_five-y_pred_five),dtype="float"))

    mse = (mse1+mse2+mse3+mse4+mse5)/5

    return mse
```

When I try to use this loss function in my NN I get the following message:

> ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure
>   that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are
>   differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round,
>   K.eval.

I couldn't figure out why this error occurs. I thought that all tf operations should be differentiable but I could also be wrong.

Thanks for any help.